# Function cvShowImage make program crash. Why? OpenCv

Tags: c, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 with Windows 8. When I call function `cvShowImage` the program crashes. I am using codeblocks and I don't know why this happens.

If I comment the line the program runs well.

The code looks as follows:

```
    IplImage *img1=NULL;
    img1=cvLoadImage("LenaComFormas.pgm",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cvShowImage("Original", img1);
    cvWaitKey(0);
```

Comment: Most probably image wasn't actually read. Can you print and check img1 values?

Comment: The image was loaded because if i do this: cvSaveImage("qwf.jpg",img1); The image is saved...

Comment: Can you print the values right after you load it?

Comment: values of img1? Well img1 is not NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working fine with Qt and opencv 2.4.3 on Windows7...possible checks you can do...

1. check links to the libraries...opencv_core231 , opencv_highgui231 ,  opencv_imgproc231...check includes to opencv2/opencv/core.hpp opencv2/opencv/highgui.hpp.
2. check the IplImage pointer img1

`IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage("",0);`

`if(img1==NULL)`

`return -1;`

3 . check the support of *.pgm images...or else get the latest opencv and try...

**EDIT..**
4 . just for check try the following..

```
#include <opencv/opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread("",0);
  imshow("TEST",image);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have other computer working right this code with windows 7. i installed exactly the same way in both computers. I The only diference is Windows 8. I dont know whats wrong. this makes me crazy..

Comment: rotating_image. Thanks with 2.4.3 it works :D. Opencv 2.3.1 has a bug with windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Because image wasn't load (`cvLoadImage` returned `NULL`). You can use [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to check it. Check the path to the file again.

Comment: The image was loaded because if i do this: cvSaveImage("qwf.jpg",img1);  The image is saved...